# Why are my threads sleeping when I specifically make them do work

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

I am learning to thread one of my scripts and I have a question. I have three classes that does their own thing:

```
class odd(object):
    def count():
        num = 1
        while True:
            num += 2

class even(object):
    def count():
        num = 0
        while True:
            num += 2

class singles(object):
    def count():
        num = 0
        while True:
            num +=1
```

And my main starts three threads:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    print('Starting...')
    t1 = Thread(name='thread1', target=even.count)
    t2 = Thread(name='thread2', target=odd.count)
    t3 = Thread(name='thread3', target=singles.count)

    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
    while True:
       pass
```

However when I do `top -H -p <pid>` to view threads spawned by my python process I see 4 total threads, 1 running, and 3 sleeping. I was expecting to see 3 total threads and 3 running. Can someone explain to me what is happening? Where is the 4th thread coming from? Why aren't all my threads running?

Comment: I can't reproduce. I run your code and get 3 threads running. You could always check they are running with prints and sleeps.

Comment: found the answer to my questions. CPython has a global lock that is held onto by each thread. This explains why most of my threads are sleeping. The 4th thread is the main thread and three others are spawned from that main.